# Ordering .bib file alphabetically

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, biblatex-chicago

I'm searching for a way to edit/re-order the entries *in the .bib file* to match the ordering defined for the bibliography. There are several questions here about ordering the bibliography, but I haven't found anything regarding ordering the .bib file itself...perhaps because it isn't possible! For instance, [Sorting bibliography according to the order in .bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203035/sorting-bibliography-according-to-the-order-in-bib-file) is the opposite of what I'm looking for. I want to sort the .bib file according to the order in the bibliography.

The reason is because I have several .bib files organized by topic, each topic file organized by when I read the source. It would save me quite a bit of time to have the entries organized so that, for instance, I could delete an entire stretch of one author's sources instead of searching for them one by one.

```
%LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}

@book{bcd,
    author          = {Mike Man},
    title           = {Title},
    year            = {2016},
    publisher       = {Books},
}

@book{cde,
    author          = {Bill Ban},
    title           = {Name},
    year            = {2009},
    publisher       = {Publisher},
}

@book{abc,
    author          = {Bill Ban},
    title           = {Something},
    year            = {2014},
    publisher       = {Somewhere},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Text.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Ideally there could be a way to reorder bib.bib such that it matches the defined ordering in the bibliography (thus, `authordate,sorting=nyt`). In this case, the intended ordering should be `cde`, `abc`, `bcd`.

Comment: don't know for sure, but nelson beebe's bibliography tools may have something useful.  see [Identifying unique entries in similar bibtex bibliography files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40713/579) for link and some other possibilities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible with `biber`'s tool mode. Suppose your .bib is "test.bib" and you have the following in "test.conf" (this is just the config file version of the "nyt" sorting scheme - see the biblatex/biber PDF docs about this).

```
<config>
  <!-- nyt SORTING -->
  <sorting>
    <presort>mm</presort>
    <sort order="1">
      <sortitem order="1">presort</sortitem>
    </sort>
    <sort order="2" final="1">
      <sortitem order="1">sortkey</sortitem>
    </sort>
    <sort order="3">
      <sortitem order="1">sortname</sortitem>
      <sortitem order="2">author</sortitem>
      <sortitem order="3">editor</sortitem>
      <sortitem order="4">translator</sortitem>
      <sortitem order="5">sorttitle</sortitem>
      <sortitem order="6">title</sortitem>
    </sort>
    <sort order="4">
      <sortitem order="1">sortyear</sortitem>
      <sortitem order="2">year</sortitem>
    </sort>
    <sort order="5">
      <sortitem order="1">sorttitle</sortitem>
      <sortitem order="2">title</sortitem>
    </sort>
    <sort order="6">
      <sortitem order="1">volume</sortitem>
      <sortitem order="2">0</sortitem>
    </sort>
  </sorting>
</config>
```

Then simply run this command:

```
biber --tool --configfile=test.conf test.bib
```

and your sorted .bib will be in `test_bibertool.bib`.

`biber` uses a default config file in tool mode which you can find by running:

```
biber --tool-config
```

you can then copy this file and edit it to your needs. You can do many things to your .bib files with tool mode such as reformatting, sorting, changing the data using sourcemaps, materialising inheritance rules etc. See the `biber` PDF documentation.

The `biber` PDF manual (currently section 3.1.7) has details of the format of the sorting specification accepted in the config file.

Comment: I get the following error
:30 parser error : Premature end of data in tag sorting line 3
</sort>

Do you know how to fix this? Apologies for resurrecting an old post

Comment: This just means that your XML config file is malformatted. You can open it in any XML editor and it will show you the error. Likely some missing tag etc.