# Management and correction of bib files in a multi-user context

Tags: bibtex

*Context*: I am writing in cooperation a long document (`book`), split into different `TeX` inputs, calling  different `bib`files, modified by several users, with potential duplicates. I am trying to homogenize and rename the used bib keys, using some "almost unique" pattern (which I can describe later), removing dups, correcting all the `bib` fields, etc. [EDIT] When the used bibkeys are cleaned, I want to gather them in another existing master `bib`file, that serves as a common reference base.

The master `bib`file has about 10.000 references, managed by Jabref. I would like to clean keys and fields from the others before appending them to the master.

As compiling can be long, even in `draft` version, I would like to focus on `\cite`, `\citep` or `\citet` (with `natbib`) occurrences only, and the related warnings and errors, to correct them.

*I am looking for tools*:

- that provide options to identify the `.bib` file of a given bibkey (for instance, appending the name of the `.bib` used after the reference),
- that identify which `.tex` input is concerned,
- that shorten the compiling part (e.g. non displaying the text outside citations).

**Basically, I would like the output pdf to display, after each reference, where the reference comes from** (`.tex` input and origin `.bib`), so that I can quickly modify the concerned `.bib` and `.tex`.

My environment is `texniccenter`, `jabref` and `miktex` (in Windows).

Comment: Use package `citeall` and go over the list of bib files. You are thinking too complicated. Oh wait, `citeall` is for the modern `biblatex` only. Sorry.

Comment: I shall look into the `citeall` doc. However, the shared document cites about 400 references, while all the bib files contain about 10.000 keys

Comment: What's the point of fixing only a subset of a dtabase? I think, all or none.

Comment: I agree. Mostly a matter of time and efficiency. My databases inherit from old bibkeys, some unrelated to the present work (the book). I am just fixing keys when I happen to need (cite) them.

Comment: Then extract a document-specific `.bib` from the `.bib` files and work with that. You can obviously correct the originals as you go through, if you want. That way, you'll have a file with the 400 keys of interest, rather than multiple files with 10,000.

Comment: a good source of `bibtex` tools is nelson beebe's site, as mentioned in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40713/579

Comment: Why not using JabRef for management? Either importing all bib files into one database and then running the [duplicate checker](http://help.jabref.org/en/FindDuplicates) or using the [shared SQL database](http://help.jabref.org/en/SQLDatabase) feature?

Comment: @koppor I do, but the master file (updated in the question) is huge, and deduplication seems less efficient